# php/mysql, how to hide rows if the sum of row is zero?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have the below code which can calculate the sum of row, but now I want to hide the row if the sum of row is zero, how to do ?

```
SELECT * , 
  Client.client_chi_name, 
  Client.client_eng_name, 
  SUM( shares_no ) AS sub_shares,
  (select sum(shares_no) FROM Shareholder
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Client ON Shareholder.client_id = Client.client_id
      WHERE Shareholder.com_no = '2040628') as total_shares
FROM Shareholder
LEFT OUTER JOIN Client ON Shareholder.client_id = Client.client_id
WHERE Shareholder.com_no = '2040628'
GROUP BY Shareholder.client_id
ORDER BY sub_shares DESC,
Shareholder.date_of_register DESC
```

[image: picture to hide zero rows]

Thank you very much for your help & support in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`HAVING` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Supposing that you have to filter out the `total_shares` that are zero:

```
.
.
GROUP BY Shareholder.client_id
HAVING total_shares > 0
ORDER BY sub_shares DESC,
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to use 'Having' you should use it. it is better way

.
.
GROUP BY ...
HAVING total_shares > 0
.
.

But since you are asking such easy question, i think you are not very strngth in SQL. So, you can alway use 'where' clause. it will work slower then Having and it is not a good approach, but it will definitly work

```
   select * from
(SELECT * , 
  Client.client_chi_name, 
  Client.client_eng_name, 
  SUM( shares_no ) AS sub_shares,
  (select sum(shares_no) FROM Shareholder
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Client ON Shareholder.client_id = Client.client_id
      WHERE Shareholder.com_no = '2040628') as total_shares
FROM Shareholder
LEFT OUTER JOIN Client ON Shareholder.client_id = Client.client_id
WHERE Shareholder.com_no = '2040628'
GROUP BY Shareholder.client_id
ORDER BY sub_shares DESC,
Shareholder.date_of_register DESC
)
where shares_no >0
```